# Remove duplicate WebPart from "Add WebPart" Menu

Tags: 2013

I'm in the process of developing some SharePoint addins, and I'm having an issue where I renamed a solution file. After I renamed it, I re-deployed it and I can add it to a page the same as always. Problem is now I have a "dead" plugin in the menu that I cannot figure out how to remove! There is only one WSP listed in the solutions lists, and it is for the newer version of the plugin.
[image]

V2 is the newer version, but I cannot get the original solution to remove itself from this menu.

Is there a way to manually remove these references to the dead solution?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can remove webparts from the web part gallary of your site.

> Goto **Site Actions > Galleries > WebPart**
>
> /_catalogs/wp/Forms/AllItems.aspx

Then search your .webpart file and remove it from the list.